# Java Hibernate select count with other columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My HQL code:

```
select count(products.id) ,products.id, products.productDescription, p.products.productFileName
    from Polls as p
    group by products.id
    order by count(products.id) desc
```

This query returns

```
Coloumn 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
3         | 2        | Product1 | ProductFilename1
2         | 1        | Product2 | ProductFilename2
```

I wish to put them in a list then display them in jsp page.

**My question is**: do I need to create new class so I can map the fields because of the count just for this query?
Any help please?

my classes are:

```
public class Polls  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Products products;
    private Users users;
    private Date voteDate;

    public Polls() {
    }

    public Polls(Products products, Users users, Date voteDate) {
       this.products = products;
       this.users = users;
       this.voteDate = voteDate;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Products getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Products products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    public Users getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public Date getVoteDate() {
        return this.voteDate;
    }

    public void setVoteDate(Date voteDate) {
        this.voteDate = voteDate;
    }
}
```

Product class:

```
public class Products  implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer id;
    private String productDescription;
    private String productFileName;
    private Set pollses = new HashSet(0);

    public Products() {
    }


    public Products(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public Products(String productDescription, String productFileName, Set pollses) {
       this.productDescription = productDescription;
       this.productFileName = productFileName;
       this.pollses = pollses;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProductDescription() {
        return this.productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }
    public String getProductFileName() {
        return this.productFileName;
    }

    public void setProductFileName(String productFileName) {
        this.productFileName = productFileName;
    }
    public Set getPollses() {
        return this.pollses;
    }

    public void setPollses(Set pollses) {
        this.pollses = pollses;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the list with an enhanced for loop like this:

```
<%
List<Object[]> myGadgets = new GadgetsRepository().getGadgetDescVotes();
for (Object p : myGadgets) {%>
    <div class="gadgetItem">
        <div><%=p[0]%>&nbsp;</div>//this don't work
    </div>
<%  }%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, though creating a new object would be cleaner and a little easier to work with. Unless you wrap it, the query you have should return a [`List<Object[]>`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select). So, to render the table you could just iterate through that collection. However, if you need to work with a specific item as the underlying type, you will need to cast it.

I am not sure what framework you are using, but something like this would work in pure jsp:

```
<c:forEach value="${collection}" var="item">
  <c:out value="${item[0]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

With an enhanced for loop, you could do something like:

```
for(Object[] c : resultSet) {
   //work with c[0], c[1], etc...
}
```

If you do create a wrapper object, you will have the advantage of having field names that document what is being displayed, and you will also have type information for the underlying fields (as opposed to having to cast from `Object`).

Comment: Yeah, that what I thought first. But i am doing a enhanced for loop on the list so what I do if I want the count?

Comment: @Thinker, I had not formatted my code before so it disappeared. I fixed that and added in an enhanced for loop. Not sure if there was something more specific you were looking for.

Comment: Nice it worked. I just didn't know that I needed to put the square brackets. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to do anything. The query returns a list of arrays that can be displayed with vanilla JSP. The only drawback is that you need to access fields by indices instead of names (row[0], row[1] etc).
2. Mapping a new object to the query results would be a major misuse of Hibernate and could backfire later on (when the same row can be modified by different objects).
3. Don't feel forced to use an ORM mapper all the time. Evidence suggests that you need a plain SQL query. In your example you are not really manipulating objects, you are querying relational data into a report. Just grab the Connection object (it's best to use the doWork method and use the connection from inside your Work object), make an ordinary query.
4. If you really hate SQL, make a simple object (could be immutable) with a constructor that takes all the columns that you need and relevant getters. Do not map the object, instead change your HQL to:

```
     select new MyAggregatedPollRow(count(products.id) ,products.id, products.productDescription, p.products.productFileName) from Polls as p
       group by products.id
       order by count(products.id) desc
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me too. My problem was that I wasn't using like 'Object[]' i was using it just 'Object'

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of how easy hibernate makes it to write methods for your tables.

You can:

Split the HQL up into 3 methods with a query in each method to get the count of the table your interested in.

Make a single method that takes a generic object and gets the count of the enity and then reuse it for any entity you see fit.